# Laravel DB query make query template (call by value)

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

My problem is about a Laravel db query. Normally every oop user defines his/her common variable in the parent class with private property and uses it from other child class because of oop reasons - re-usability ... And now my problem is when I define a variable for DB query with private key, I write a getter method (like a normal person) because I don't want change original common query parts but it is always calling by reference.

Example (Parent Class):

```
$this->userConfirmedPackageData = DB::table('payments')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'payments.user_id')->
         *.....continue with more join*
        ->join('subjects', 'subjects.id', '=', 'classroom_subject.subject_id')
        ->where(['payments.confirmed' => 1, 'payments.user_id' => $this->currentUser->getUserId()]);
```

After defining that common part of query I want to use it like template for my all other child class queries, but if I use it in the same class like below (Child Class):

```
$firstQuery = $this->getUserConfirmedPackageData()->join("aTable")->where("something.id",3)->get(["something.id"]);
$secondQuery = $this->getUserConfirmedPackageData()->join("bTable")->where("somethingDifferentTable.user_id",1111)->take(5)->get(["somethingDifferentTable.name"]);
```

My precious private variable changes (gets stuck) after the first get method!

I know DB table cannot finish until I say "get" but is there any way to use queries common part like this? I wrote all the code for explanation, they could  have a syntax error, but it's not about code it's about logic. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your code, you need to put your query into a regular method so that the query object gets recreated on each call. If you put it into a property (`$this->userConfirmedPackageData`), the query object is reused, even though you're calling the getter method (`$this->getUserConfirmedPackageData()`).

I'd recommend something like the following:

```
public function userConfirmedPackageQuery() {
    return DB::table('payments')
         ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'payments.user_id')->
         // *.....continue with more join*
         ->join('subjects', 'subjects.id', '=', 'classroom_subject.subject_id')
         ->where(['payments.confirmed' => 1, 'payments.user_id' => $this->currentUser->getUserId()]);
}
```

Use it like:

```
$firstQuery = $this->userConfirmedPackageQuery()->join("aTable")->where("something.id",3)->get(["something.id"]);
$secondQuery = $this->userConfirmedPackageQuery()->join("bTable")->where("somethingDifferentTable.user_id",1111)->take(5)->get(["somethingDifferentTable.name"]);
```